# Delete intersection between two lists

Tags: python, django

I have two lists of objects:

```
m2m_links = mymodel._meta.many_to_many
o2m_links = mymodel._meta.get_all_related_objects()
```

There is an object in o2m_links that I wish to omit/delete.  It can be identified in the following way:

```
for r in m2m_links:
    if not r.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
        # Delete o2m_links object that has the same name as r.rel.through._meta.object_name
```

**How can I delete the o2m_links objects that match the criteria hit by this loop?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a set and a list comprehension to filter the list:

```
names_to_remove = set([r.rel.through._meta.object_name for r in m2m_links if not r.rel.through._meta.auto_created])
filtered_list = [r for r in o2m_links if r.rel.through._meta.object_name in names_to_remove]
```

Comment: Altered second line because .get_all_related_objects() doesn't have an attribute "rel". filtered_list = [r for r in o2m_links if r.opts.verbose_name not in names_to_remove]

Answer (score 31):

to remove the intersection between two list you should use set

```
a = set(range(10))
b = set(range(5,15))
a-b
>>set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b-a
>>set([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `remove`:

```
some_list.remove(some_item)
```

See: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

However, if the item doesn't match, it'll raise a `ValueError`, so unless you're sure the item is actually in the list, catch the error.