# Remove intersection from two lists in python

Tags: python

Given two lists, what is the best way to remove the intersection of the two?  For example, given:

```
a = [2,2,2,3]
b = [2,2,5]
```

I want to return:

```
a = [2,3]
b = [5]
```

Comment: Why do you remove only *one* `2` from the first list?

Comment: Also, what is the criteria of the sizes of these lists? Is it always going to be one list that is smaller than the other? Can they be equal lengths? Can you please provide more information around the boundaries of this type of filtering?

Comment: This has already been answered:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331627/delete-intersection-between-two-lists

Comment: Suppose `a = [1, 2, 4, 3, 2]` and `b = [3, 2]`. What should the result be? As in, should you remove the first occurrence of `2` in `a` and thus get `a = [1, 4, 2]`, or remove the section that matches `b` best, i.e. `a = [1, 2, 4]`?

Comment: Willem - you are correct, should have removed both twos.

Comment: No criteria on size - they cannot be null, but nothing else.  Which one to remove doens't matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume you wish to handle the general case (same elements appear more than once in each list), the so called **multiset**.

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
intersection = Counter(a) & Counter(b)
multiset_a_without_common = Counter(a) - intersection
multiset_b_without_common = Counter(b) - intersection
new_a = list(multiset_a_without_common.elements())
new_b = list(multiset_b_without_common.elements())
```

For your values of `a`, `b`, you'll get:

```
a = [2,2,2,3]
b = [2,2,5]
new_a = [2, 3]
new_b = [5]
```

Note that for a special case of each element appearing exactly once, you can use the standard [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), as the other answers are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the two lists and remove elements as you find an intersect point as the following:

```
a = [2, 2, 2, 3]
b = [2, 2, 5]
delete = []
for c in a:
    for n in b:
        if n == c:
            delete.append(c)
            delete.append(n)
            break
    a.remove(delete[0])
    b.remove(delete[1])
    delete = []
print a
print b
```

output:

```
[2, 3]
[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2,2,2,3]
b = [2,2,5]
for i in list(b): #I call list() on b because otherwise I can't remove from it during the for loop.
    if i in a:
        a.remove(i)
        b.remove(i)
```

Output:

```
a = [2, 3]
b = [5]
```