# Remove common terms from two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=list(input()) 
y=list(input()) 
for a in x:
    if a in y:
        x.remove(a)
        y.remove(a)
print(x, y)
```

I can't get the exact answer for this code if I gave input like this

```
x = "lilly" 
y ="daliya"
```

The output must be

```
(l,l) (d, a, a)
```

But it is

```
(i, l, l) (d, a, i, a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500888/removing-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete intersection between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331627/delete-intersection-between-two-lists)

Comment: Start using print statement as debugger by printing for x/y each a variable. Then you can see in which order things are handled and figure it out yourself.

Comment: You just need to iterate on a copy of x via `x[:]` and you should not get this error anymore, check my answer below @Kumaresh !

Answer (score 2):

Iterate on the copies of `x`, using list slicing `arr[:]` otherwise you are modifying the same list you are iterating on.

```
x=list('lilly')
y=list('daliya')
for a in x[:]:
    if a in y:
        x.remove(a)
        y.remove(a)
print(x, y)
```

The output will then be

```
['l', 'l'] ['d', 'a', 'a']
```