# How to remove duplicates in an array in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from another and returns the result. Here is what i have so far:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    for e in b[:]:
        for i in a:
            a.remove(i)
    return a


in1 = [1, 2, 2]
in2 = [1]
print(array_diff(in1, in2))
```

I have two sample tests that i'd like to run.

```
Test.assert_equals(array_diff([1,2,2], [1]), [2,2], "a was [1,2,2], b was [1], expected [2,2]")
Test.assert_equals(array_diff([1,2,2], [2]), [1], "a was [1,2,2], b was [2], expected [1]")
```

How would i be able to remove the same value more than once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete intersection between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331627/delete-intersection-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 1):

```
array_diff = lambda a, b: [ i for i in a if i not in b]

array_diff(in1,[1])
 [2, 2]

array_diff(in1,[2])
 [1]
```